# Azure Function is not triggerd after putting a message to a queue in service bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have a queue in a service bus. After putting a message into a queue an azure logic app and an azure functions should betriggered and process the content.
My Azure logic app is triggered but my azure funcction is not triggered. My code for azure function:

```
[FunctionName("ReadMEssageFromQueue")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("messagequeue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    }
```

host json:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
  
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "******" // connection string of my service bus
  }
}
```

should I set something in service bus queue to send message to both ressources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Service Bus Queue messages are picked up by only one processor. So I think in your case, the logic app is picking up and consuming the message first and the message is not available for the function to process. You can try temporarily disabling the logic app and letting function pick the message to confirm this.

Ref: [azure-service-bus-queue-with-multiple-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277200/azure-service-bus-queue-with-multiple-listeners-competing-consumers-with-queue/53277505)

You can trigger the Azure function from your logic app (not sure if it'll help your use case), or you can use Azure Service Bus topics as topics support the model where multiple consumers can [subscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions) to a topic.
The former option might be a better approach for you from [cost](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/service-bus/) perspective, as you'd need to use Standard tier of service bus in order to use topics feature, which means additional cost for you over your current setup.

Also, you might want to use some other name for service bus connection string as [AzureWebJobsStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage) is used for storage account connection string